# Why can't I send files via my laptop's bluetooth?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

Every time I try to send a file via my laptop's Bluetooth I get this error:
[image: ERROR]
So I headed over to my device manager and tried to update the drivers but it says that the device drivers could not be found and that I should contact the vendor.
I tried it on my phone as well as my friend's and both the times I get the same error. 
Both of us own Nokia phones.
Previously I could send files via bluetooth but now I can't.
Help me out!
The devices were turned on and their visibility was *shown to all*
[image: Device Mgr]
Also:
[image]

Comment: Go to the support page for you computer and download the drivers from there.

Comment: Woops! sorry for that!

Comment: You need to figure out what has changed between when you could send files and now.  Without this information we can't help you.  My guess you upgrdaded your operating system and you have not downloaded a driver that is supported by said operating system.

Comment: I updated the BIOS. Neither HP nor Microsoft has any Bluetooth drivers available for download

Comment: What is your computer model and OS?

Comment: HP DV4-2126tx running a Win7 Home Premium

Comment: Did you try this: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4074361&prodNameId=4168971&swEnvOID=4062&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ob-76382-1

Comment: Hp's site is so confusing.. I never even found that thing!

Comment: So it worked or not?

Comment: Nop :/ I will call the HP guys and ask them to fix it. I have to replace my dying HDD so I wont solve it now :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Start icon, search for *bluetooth* and select *Change Bluetooth settings*.
2. Select *Allow Bluetooth devices to find this computer* then select *Show the Bluetooth icon in the notification area*.
3. Right click on the Bluetooth icon in the notification area, add a device, and finally send and receive files.